# Puppeteer: How to scrape data on Refresh Page From Multiple Pages/Tabs

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I have Below code to **scrape** data from one page

```js
 page.on('load',() => {
        console.log('load event fired');
    });
```

This code will work for only one Tab/Page. I need to find solution for Multiple Pages/Tabs